# how to add a preloader in react router 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I'm trying to add a pre-loader in my personal site, and the problem is that is cannot make it work. As you can see in image

I'm try to render it before router so that it runs before anything else.

code is simple

```
const [screenLoading, setScreenLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setScreenLoading(true);
  setTimeout(() => {
    setScreenLoading(false);
  }, 1000);
}, []);
```

after a sec state will go false and site will load. but I am getting this error "Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component." which makes sense, but I don't have any return function to run the code inside.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import './index.css'
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

//contexts
// import { MousePos } from './mousePosContext';

//components
import Header from './Header'
// import Footer from './Footer'
import ErrorPage from "./error-page";

//pages
import Home from './Home'
import Profile from "./Profile"
import Works from "./Works"
import Blogs from "./Blogs"
import Wm from "./works/web-monitization"
import Ss from "./works/scheduling-system"
import Bs from "./works/bharatSteel"

import Load from "./loader"

const [screenLoading, setScreenLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setScreenLoading(true);
  setTimeout(() => {
    setScreenLoading(false);
  }, 1000);
}, []);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Header />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        element: <Home />,
        index: true,
        loader: async () => {
          console.log("router loader called")
          const test = (x) => {
            console.log(x)
          }
          return test
        }
      },
      {
        path: "/profile",
        element: <Profile />,
      },
      {
        path: "/works",
        element: <Works />,
      },
      {
        path: "/works/web-monetization",
        element: <Wm />
      },
      {
        path: "works/input-validaton",
        element: <Wm />
      },
      {
        path: "works/scheduling-system",
        element: <Ss proji="scheduling-system" />
      },
      {
        path: "works/bharat-steel",
        element: <Bs proji="scheduling-system" />
      },
      {
        path: "blogs",
        element: <Blogs />
      },
      {
        path: "loader",
        element: <Load />
      }
    ]
  }
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <div className='layout'>
    {screenLoading
      ? <Load />
      : <RouterProvider router={router} />
    }
  </div>
)
```

So can someone tell me how to implement it, and if there is any other way to implement preloader with React-Router? The loader needs to run every time site loads for first time regard less of which page is being loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is unrelated to the react-router This line

```
const [screenLoading, setScreenLoading] = useState(false);
```

It's invalid, you can't use `useState` outside of a component body. Same with `useEffect`

Create a component to fix that:

```
const Wrapper = () => {
  const [screenLoading, setScreenLoading] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
  setScreenLoading(true);
  setTimeout(() => {
    setScreenLoading(false);
  }, 1000);
}, []);

  return <div className='layout'>
    {screenLoading? <Load /> :
    <RouterProvider router={router} />}
  </div>
}
```

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<Wrapper />)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The issue here is that you are using React hooks outside any React component. This breaks the [Rules of Hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

## Solution

Konrad's answer provides a solution to allow you to use the React hooks and correctly conditionally render your loading UI.

I don't think you need to re-invent the wheel though, the `RouterProvider` component has a [fallbackElement](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/router-provider#fallbackelement) prop to render while a route is loading.

> If you are not server rendering your app, `createBrowserRouter` will
> initiate all matching route loaders when it mounts. During this time,
> you can provide a `fallbackElement` to give the user some indication
> that the app is working. Make that static hosting TTFB count!

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <div className='layout'>
    <RouterProvider router={router} fallbackElement={<Load />} />
  </div>
);
```